# How to get a Max() Value in a Subselect after a COUNT was used

Tags: mysql

I have two tables to JOIN and work with. i have to count some things at the start and after that i have to write a subquery to show the maxNumber of what i had calculated before. I don't know how to get the subquery right.

Here are the two tables:

```
1. course
coursNr(key)
topic
memberNR

2. courseo
coursNr(key)
persNr
```

I managed to get the first step right as shown below but i couldn't get the subquery right.

```
select courseo.coursNr, course.topic, count(courseo.persNr)
from courseo, course 
WHERE course.coursNr = courseo.coursNr
group by courseo.coursNr
//here follows the subquery
Where courseo.persNr IN (Select MAX (courseo.persNr)
from curseo)
```

until before the subquery i get this:

```
courseNR topic        count(courseo.persNr)
1        database     6
2        network      8
3        organisation 2
```

etc. 
but i want only the max count to be shown like this

```
courseNR topic    count(courseo.persNr)
2        network  8
```

Comment: "`group by kursbelegung.KursNr`" -- you seem to have forgotten to translate that one. Either translate all or nothing (which is probably the best idea to prevent errors sneaking in). And you should consider using explicit `JOIN` syntax rather than using commas in the `FROM`.

Comment: what is the advantage to use the explicit join syntax? i did it before with an inner join but i couldnt't figure out how to go on

Comment: It's clearer to read and maintain e.g. when switching from an inner join to an outer join. And mixing both, e.g. when appending another join with explicit syntax, may produce funny results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `max()` you can order you data by count and take only row with the biggest number.

```
select courseo.coursNr, course.topic, count(courseo.persNr) as cnt
from courseo, course 
WHERE course.coursNr = courseo.coursNr
group by kursbelegung.KursNr
order by cnt desc
limit 1
```

Comment: This seems to be right and Working. I was in the wrong trip that in order to make an subdelect or query i needed to use WHERE IN.